# Is it possible to pass a generic model to a JsonResult action from an ajax call?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I'm creating a javascript function that will invoke ajax call to validate the model of a form.

```
function ValidateModel(formID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Custom/ValidateModel',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#' + formID).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {

        // code remove for brevity  

        }
    });
}
```

That will be handled by this Action in the CustomController

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ValidateModel(CustomModel model)
    {          
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                 // code remove for brevity
            }
            return Json(customObject, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);

    }
```

If I will pass a form with CustomModel object the auto binding works just fine. What I want to create is a generic handler on the server to validate the model. I want to achieve it with something like this:

```
public ActionResult ValidateModel(GenericModel model)
{

}
```

so that when I can pass different forms with different model types on the server.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Could you use an interface that all your models implement and have

```
public ActionResult ValidateModel(IViewModel model)
{

}
```

You'd be able to pass any model that implements the IViewModel interface.

Or maybe you could use an abstract base class?